# div draw behind other div

Tags: html, css

i'm really lost on some code. Im trying to draw a dayview calendar with appointments in it. It was based on a table however i replaced it by divs. The table view originally had the same problem, hence i rewrote it to divs. Chrome was displaying it rightly, though with use of tables.

I have made a jsfiddle so you can check it all out. http://jsfiddle.net/dvr9Z/107/

and as you can see, the appointments are draw behind the other divs? i tried using z-index, but that didnt work. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible with the way your code works, you should get success by putting the floating div on the same structural level as the rows. That is, have the black box as a child of the day's container div, rather than a child of the time slot

Comment: i think you're right.... will make calculations on the top and bottom margin different and place them at the container. thanks for the thoughts

Answer (score 0):

SmokeyPHP is correct. Something like this is what you're looking for. Place the black box as a child of the container and use css top property to set the vertical position.

http://jsfiddle.net/dvr9Z/118/

I don't think it can be done the current way your html divs are written.